# Why is the Essentials Dungeon Master Kit so expensive/hard to find?

Tags: dnd-4e

It looks like the [Essentials Dungeon Master Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786956305) for 4e is hard to find new, and the new copies I can find are really expensive. Is this because it is out of date or out of print? Is there a better/updated item I should be looking for instead? The monster vault, red box, player compendium, etc are all easy to find and affordable so it is strange to me that this isn't.

Comment: Without knowing, I'd guess that it's out of print.

Comment: Are you talking about the 4e essentials redbox? http://www.amazon.com/Dungeons-Dragons-Fantasy-Roleplaying-Game/dp/0786956291/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1379074408&sr=8-3&keywords=essentials+red+box

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith no. This is about this guy: http://www.amazon.com/Dungeon-Masters-Kit-Essential-Dungeons/dp/0786956305/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1379084082&sr=8-1&keywords=dm+kit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This product, the [Dungeon Master's Kit](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/244640000) from the Essentials line, was first released October 2010. Since the announcement of DnD Next, Wizards has been [slowly phasing out 4e](http://www.critical-hits.com/blog/2012/12/07/the-exaggerated-death-of-4th-edition/) products. While I can't find any official reference to the product being out of print, I suspect it might well have been quietly removed from print.

It might be easier to find the Dungeon Master's Guide, which is not in the Essentials line but instead comes from the main line of products and should contain the same rules. The [Deluxe DM Screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786957433) is in stock at Amazon, and the dungeon tiles also seem relatively easy to find if you're looking for map resources. You've already mentioned the monster vaults; some other adventures, like "Madness at Gardmore Abbey", also come with battle mats and tokens that might be useful.

Comment: For a line of products which was supposed to be "always in print", this is unfortunate at best.

Comment: The kit contains a lot of things (two adventures, DM screen, battle mats, counters) that aren't in the DMG.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This is true. I assumed, possibly incorrectly, that they needed the rules. I'll add some other products.

Comment: a link to the two monster vaults is probably also relevant here and tokens are a big part of the package with the DM Kit. Sadly if that adventure is OoP then we've lost a rather good pre-written campaign :(

Answer (score 11):

**You can now get it as a PDF online**

The Dungeon Master's Kit has been added on [DriveThruRPG.com](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/121978/Dungeon-Masters-Kit-%284e%29?filters=0_0_44834_0_0)

> If you're a Dungeons & Dragons player looking forward to your first experience as the Dungeon Master, this box contains everything you need to get started, including expert advice on making your game the best it can be. Create monster-infested dungeons, gather your friends, and let the fun begin. In the Dungeons & Dragons world you create, anything is possible—the only limit is your imagination!
>
> Contents:
>
> - Dungeon Master's Book, containing everything you need to build and run exciting D&D adventures
> - 2 books containing "Reavers of Harkenwold," a ready-to-play two-part adventure
>
> NOTE: This is a digital download product and does not include the double-sided, fold-out battle maps; the 3 sheets of cut-out hero and monster tokens; or the fold-out, four-panel DM's screen that were included in the original physical product.

Comment: Why they didn't include the maps and tokens as printable PDFs is beyond me.